# Проблема с компиляцией в среде Code Blocks

Tags: c++, windows, codeblocks

Code Blocks не компилирует файл, в пути к которому содержатся русские символы. Выдаёт ошибку:

```
||=== Build file: "no target" in "no project" (compiler: unknown) ===|
||error: D:\repos\rep1\????? ?????\???\???????\main.cpp: Invalid argument|
||error: no input files|
||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Компилятор выставлен GNU GCC Compiler. Система Windows 10 Pro, английская версия (но русская клавиатура присутствует). Можно это как-то вылечить?

Comment: Сохранить там где нет русских букв?

Comment: не хочется - у меня это часть пути в уже имеющемся репозитории (

Comment: Т. Е. У вас и репозиторий назван кириллицей? Дело в том что кириллица хранится в расширенной части кодировки unicode и должна правильно распознаться. Ищите все упоминания кодировки в кодеблокс и ставьте utf.

Comment: g++ поставить как компилятор должно помочь

Comment: g++ в винде это mingw, а он у меня и стоит

Comment: Так вы пишете что выставлен gcc. Искренне советую исправить все имена на латиницу и забыть о куче проблем с многобайтными кодировками.

Comment: Название компилятора в настройках стоит как GNU GCC [скрин](https://a.radikal.ru/a19/1912/b7/bb0ad03612e2.png)

Comment: Там выпадающий список. Выберите g++. g++ и gcc это разные компиляторы.

Comment: Нету там такого: [скрин](https://d.radikal.ru/d41/1912/2b/e2f3a3f96392.png)

Comment: *"Можно это как-то вылечить?"* Вариант "поставить нормальную IDE" - считается? :) Скачайте себе VSCode и собирайте каким-нибудь make/cmake...

Comment: Тогда ни как. gcc  такие символы не поддерживает. Тем более у вас пробел в имени. Это вообще моветон.

Comment: На русской винде проблем с кириллицей в пути не было... За вариант с VSCode спасибо, попробую. Я думал на Qt перейти, но там отдельный файл не ясно, как скомпилировать, а создавать каждый раз проект не хочется... За возможность компилить один main я и ценил CB...

Comment: VSCode тоже так умеет, с нужными плагинами. (`Code Runner` или что-то такое).

Comment: Напишите ваш совет про VSCode в виде ответа, если несложно. Я в ближайшие пару дней проверю, что он компилит по 1 файлу и проблем таких не имеет, и если с CB не найдётся решения - ваш ответ приму.

Comment: @zcorvid Расширением на запуск одного файла я не пользовался, только слышал про него. Лучше сами напишете, если понравится.

Comment: Что вам мешает компилировать из командной строки тем компилятором, которым хотите? Тем более, если там 1 файл.

Comment: это нам за грехи наши, нечего было бороться с кибернетикой - "продажной девкой империализма", глядишь, и кодовая страница была бы по умолчанию и BIOS (вернее БСВВ) был бы в кириллице :D